# Trying to get a plane at a certain distance and angle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, solidworks

I'm working with solidworks and trying to make a plane at a certain distance and angle from another plane.

Just for some context, I want to do something like this:
[image: m]

My plan was to create a plane at the reference and then make a sketch on the new plane and convert entities so that the feature on the bottom right extends to the back.

I know I can do it like this, and extrude out the sketch, then make another sketch on the side face:
[image]

But Im wondering if theres a more direct/efficient way?

Comment: How is this part manufactured? Is it bent sheet metal? If so, use the sheet metal tools...

Comment: When you ask if there's a more efficient way. What you consider more efficient? If you plan to bend the plate like @Jonathan R Swift said the best is with sheet metal tools. If by efficient you want flexibility for changing geometry the way you've done is the best.

Comment: If you want flexibility for changing geometry you should *avoid* defining a plane based on a generated surface, or sketching directly on a surface - SolidWorks is notorious for loosing references to surfaces, since the internal Face ID numbers can change so easily if you adjust something further up the history tree. For a part this simple it's not so bad, but for a complex model a broken reference like that could cause days of cleanup...

Answer (score 1):

You can model the part at 90 degrees, and then use the Move Face tool to rotate the feature about the top connecting edge.

N.B. You can select features (as well as single faces) when picking which faces to move.

This whole model can be made with four features, and no additional planes or reference geometry beyond the base planes.

1. an extrude from above for the 'L' bracket
2. A cut from the front to add slots and to round off the end.
3. An extrude from the front for the 'notched' plate, shown blue in the image below.
4. Move face, to rotate it into position, shown yellow in the image below.

Again, the key point to take away from this is *editability*. You should be able to change any one dimension without the rest of the model needing to be manually updated. Selecting the Extrude feature (made in step 3) as the input for the Move face (step 4) means that even if you edit the extrude to have extra holes or to remove a slot, the move face will still work. Manually selecting the faces may cause this feature to fail as new faces appear or old faces are removed.

[image: Rotate Face Demo]